# Generalizing code to work with any number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I generalize the following code so it would work for any number of cols?

```
if (totalColls==4){
    $(aclst).eq(0).css({"top":itlh*0+"px", "left":itlwi*0+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(1).css({"top":itlh*0+"px", "left":itlwi*1+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(2).css({"top":itlh*0+"px", "left":itlwi*2+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(3).css({"top":itlh*0+"px", "left":itlwi*3+"px"});

    $(aclst).eq(4).css({"top":itlh*1+"px", "left":itlwi*0+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(5).css({"top":itlh*1+"px", "left":itlwi*1+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(6).css({"top":itlh*1+"px", "left":itlwi*2+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(7).css({"top":itlh*1+"px", "left":itlwi*3+"px"});

    $(aclst).eq(8).css({"top":itlh*2+"px", "left":itlwi*0+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(9).css({"top":itlh*2+"px", "left":itlwi*1+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(10).css({"top":itlh*2+"px", "left":itlwi*2+"px"});
    $(aclst).eq(11).css({"top":itlh*2+"px", "left":itlwi*3+"px"});
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain further what you're trying to do? As it stands, the question you've asked doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @KabirUddin I don't know if the upvote on the answer below is from you, but if the answer solves your issue, please award it the green tick so that David Conde receives the proper reward for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any amount of rows or columns.

- The jQuery **$(aclst).each()** function iterates all the elements and provides the proper index and DOM node to the callback function.
- The **Math.floor(index / totalColls)** call returns the row number, starting with 0.
- The **index % totalColls** call returns the column number, starting with 0.

Here's how it looks when you iterate all the elements.

```
$(aclst).each(function(index, element) {

    $(element).css({
        "top" : (itlh * Math.floor(index / totalColls)) + "px",
        "left": (itlwi * index % totalColls) +"px"
    });

});
```

Comment: Your question decrypting skills are amazing!